# Backup routine from a Windows 7 machine

Tags: backup, rsync

Can anyone recommend a program that automatically runs a backup on a given local path to a network destination (just sync, I only need an exact copy of the folder on the network location)? It is important that this program automatically runs the backup process even if the user is not logged in to the windows 7 machine.
Rsync or just network destination, both will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

maybe robocopy will do if you are only on Win7

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=WS.10%29.aspx